# c++ recursive function wont exit when condition is meet

Tags: c++, recursion, return

I need some help.  I have a recursive function, in c++, that simply breaks apart a string(all numbers) and adds up the characters to see if its total is less than 9.  if not it calls itself again until the condition is meet.  So far everything it is working untill the end when my condition is meet it calls the function one more time.  This obviously messes up the value of the variable that I am trying to assign it to.  I referred to many references and it seems like my syntax is correct?  Any help on why my function calls its self one last time.

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
int finalNumber =0;

// set finalNumber

finalNumber = sumTotal(sumInput);

int sumTotal(int sumInputToString)
{

    stringstream strToInt;
    string convertedInt;

    strToInt << sumInputToString;
    convertedInt= strToInt.str();

    int sum = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < convertedInt.length(); i++)
    {
        sum += (int)convertedInt[i] - 48;
    }

    if (sum > 9)
    {
        sumTotal(sum);
    }
    return sum; //ONCE SUM IS LESS THAN 9,which is what i want, 
                //MY PROGRAM AUTOMATICALLY JUMPS UP TWO LINES does it one 
                //more time than it will escape.
}
```

I have tried everything from putting my return in a else{} and swapping my if else conditions  so my return would be in my if. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: As @ahenderson - that makes the whole thing in run away mode. BTW - Try to avoid recusion. Usually ends in tears

Comment: Are you saying that the program TERMINATES with the wrong value or just stuck? Since if the value is smaller than 10 then call it one more time should not change the result.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't the statement inside the condition be:

```
if (sum > 9)
{
    sum = sumTotal(sum);
}
```

Otherwise, you're just calling

```
if (sum > 9)
{
    sumTotal(sum);
}
return sum;
```

which does nothing (i.e. doesn't contribute to the final output).

Comment: Will this affect termination?

Comment: @ZiyaoWei it will affect the returned number.

Comment: Yeah I know:) Just one more bug. EDIT: I just noticed the OP mentioned nothing about termination.

Comment: I usually prefer a `if (sum <= 9) return sum;` at the top of the function, and a simple `return sumTotal(sum);` at the end. Recursion is much easier to grasp when the termination condition is put at the top.

Answer (score 1):

Based on this comment

> MY PROGRAM AUTOMATICALLY JUMPS UP TWO LINES

I may suggest you see this in the debugger. Jumping up 2 lines itself is correct -- you move up on the function stack (i.e. return to the function which called yours -- and it is again `sumTotal`). So are you sure that after everything is done function really starts from the beginning?

One more thing to think about: if initial value of `sumInputToString` is less than 10 your code will be executed anyway. Do you want it really?

And few advices not related with your question directly. It's very difficult to understand what your function should really do. For any complex algorithm (and this may be considered as complex because you use resursion) you must have a good function comment. I would suggest something like this:

> This function first calculates the sum of all digits in the given
>   number. If the result is less or equal than 9 it is returned. If not,
>   we continue with this sum as a given number.

You may also include short sentense why do you need it (because it may seem strange at the first glance):

> This function can be used to figure out whether some number is divisible by 3 or not.

After wtirting such a comment you are starting to understand what the logic should be and may realize that you don't need a recursion here. And transform your code into something like this:

```
// Function comment
int CalculateRecursiveSumOfDigits(int val) {
    while (val > 9) {
        val = CalculateSumOfDigits(val); // TODO: implement this function
    }

    return val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the least efficient way to steal your neighbor's electricity but sure..

Your program isn't jumping back two lines, your program popped the last recursion instance from the stack, you have to make sure that it would successfully exit the function call per nested function call.

Comment: Also, check against [this][1] 


  [1]: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

If you're doing everything right, and if you know how to handle exposed shared memory like this, then you're probably being tripped up by the fact that namespace scoping at compile time will not obey the list above if there `#pragma once` or their equivalents are being ignored or improperly parsed.

Comment: For example if you have a hidden `Using namespace std;` within some other header that you're including in your main file as a .h while using only std:: type syntax within your main file, that the blanket using namespace was called in scope (technically undefined behavior until you consult specific version of compiler because they vary between VC++ and clang or g++ and between different versions of the same compiler).

Comment: In general, it is very bad form to leave something like this, unless you have something else in mind, or if you have been very short on time and by extension funding and you intend on leaving a medium-level mistake that would be found by the hopefully competent person deploying your program while bypassing the incompetent boss who put you in such a position.